# Enable Vista startup programs

Tags: windows-vista, boot

I want to be able to add some of my programs onto my laptop, so that they automatically start when I turn my computer on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start menu, All programs, scroll down to Startup. Right click and Open. Then make a shortcut of the program you want and drag/copy into this folder.

[image]